# Promise inside of forEach in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
original_test(){
    var arr=[1,2,3]
    arr.forEach((a: any) => {
        console.log("Before")
        this.test().then(()=>{
            console.log("After")
        });
    });
}
test(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(true)
    });
 }
```

My problem is that I want my code to wait for the next iteration of forEach (until the promise completes). That means I want as console output:

"Before"

"After"

"Before"

"After"

"Before"

"After"

And what I get is:

"Before"

"Before"

"Before"

"After"

"After"

"After"

Many thanks!

Comment: make your `original_test()` async then use `await this.test()` in for loop

Comment: `.forEach()` will not wait for promises to resolve. Use  a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
async original_test() {
    var arr=[1, 2, 3];
    for(const item of arr) {
        console.log("Before")
        await this.test()
        console.log("After")
    }
};
```